# How to extract text using action class in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written code to copy text using action class of selenium webdriver. All I have been able to do is to drag cursor around the text and copy it.

Code snippet :

```
Actions a = action.clickAndHold(element)
                        .moveToElement(element1)
                        .release()
                        .keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
                    .sendKeys("c")
                        .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL);
a.perform();
```

Now how do I print this text on display console using java?

Comment: Why not just use: element.getText();?

Comment: That way I can't copy required text .

Comment: @sujay You're still not being specific enough. WHY can't you do that? What is wrong with the method? Are you not able to select the right WebElements? Are you seeing text that cannot be accessed via that method?

Answer (score 0):

You should really just use [`WebElement#getText()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText%28%29). If you need to get the text of several elements, simply concatenate it. It will be much easier, much more reliable and it will work on every browser and OS.

But since you asked:

```
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
System.out.println(clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor));
```